# None in if condition, how to handle missing data?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, missing-data, nonetype

If the value of `age` is missing I want to create a variable with the value of `1`. Instead everything is `None` in the output of the `Value` column.

```
raw_data1 = {'id': [1,2,3,5],
    'age': [0, np.nan, 10, 2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data1, columns = ['id','age'])


def my_test(b):
    if b is None:
        return 1


df1['Value'] = df1.apply(lambda row: my_test(row['age']), axis=1)
```

How can implement it?  I know that there are several ways, but I would like to focus on the use of a function, (`def my_test` etc.).

Comment: The `my_test` method does return `None` if `b` is not `None`. Adding `return b` after the `if` should fix that.

Comment: do you mean like this?    if return b is None: (this does not work, thanks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can use:

```
df1['value'] = np.where(df1['age'].isnull(), 1, '')
```

Output:

```
   id   age value
0   1   0.0      
1   2   NaN     1
2   3  10.0      
3   5   2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` for this

```
df1['Value'] = df1['age'].map(lambda x : 1 if np.isnan(x) else np.nan)
```

If you want to make use of your function, you can use `map` like this

```
def my_test(b):
    if np.isnan(b):
        return 1
    else:
        return np.nan

df1['Value'] = df1['age'].map(lambda x : my_test(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row.get('age')` instead of `row['age']`.

`get()` returns null if `age` is not inside the dict

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead,

```
>>> df1.value = df1.age.isna().astype(int)
>>> df1
    id   age  value
 0   1   0.0      0
 1   2   NaN      1
 2   3  10.0      0
 3   5   2.0      0
```